# How to convert a string to int in aspx source page

Tags: c#, asp.net, type-conversion, bind, tabindex

Hi `TabIndex` accepts only int type, using like this throws exception `TabIndex='<%#Bind("Id"))` Have to convert to int and store the binded value.. How can i do this in aspx source page not in code behind?  Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

use like this if it is inside gridview if the Id property is not int.

```
TabIndex='<%# Int32.Parse(Eval("Id").ToString())>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
TabIndex='<%#Bind(int.parse("Id")))>'
```